# BeanLocator has not been set (Installing Liferay on Tomcat 7.0)

Tags: java, apache, jsp, tomcat, liferay

I'm looking to install the Liferay portal on Tomcat **without** using the bundle.

Here a link to the tutorial I'm following:
https://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.1/user-guide/-/ai/lp-6-1-ugen11-installing-liferay-on-tomcat-7-0

Tomcat is running at localhost:8080 as expected, but the Liferay portal is throwing an error. I've followed these directions twice now and can't find a way around it:

```
HTTP Status 500 - com.liferay.portal.kernel.bean.BeanLocatorException: BeanLocator has not been set
```

When I navigate to index.jsp (in the webapps/root folder) the line at fault is line #57.

```
56   else {
57   redirect = PortalUtil.getHomeURL(request);
58   }
```

According to the Liferay forums, I'm not the first to run into this error, but I wasn't able to find a solution. Thoughts?

Additional Notes:

Operating System: Windows 7

Liferay Portal Source: liferay-portal-src-6.2-ce-ga2

Liferay Portal War: liferay-portal-6.2.0-ce-ga1-20131101192857659.war

Apache Tomcat Version 7.0.53: apache-tomcat-7.0.53

Comment: 1.Do you have put the `portal-service.jar` to `~/tomcat/lib/ext`?  2. Why not to use default Liferay bundle?

Comment: Hi, Have you tried stopping your antivirus, deleting contents of  work, temp folder and restart?

Comment: The error was that Liferay portal source and Liferay portal war were different versions (6.2 ce ga2 and 6.2.0 ce ga1). I changed them to be the same version and got it working. Thanks!